# How to replace string in a file with value of variable using python and save updated content as new file

Tags: python, string, variables

Trying to update string in file with value generated by my code not sure what is the best way to do so.

```
from datetime import datetime

import sys
import time
today = datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
a = 546
color = "#F1C40F"
replacements = {'SCORE':'{}', 'CURRDATE':'{}', 'COLORCODE':'{}'}.format(a, today, color)

with open('/home/kali/Desktop/template.txt') as infile, open('/home/kali/Desktop/updatedtemplate.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/replace.py", line 8, in <module>
    replacements = {'CYBERSCORE':'{}', 'CURRDATE':'{}', 'COLORCODE':'{}'}.format(a, today, color)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: you can't format dictionaries. use this `replacements = {'SCORE':a, 'CURRDATE':today, 'COLORCODE':color}` instead of this ` replacements = {'SCORE':'{}', 'CURRDATE':'{}', 'COLORCODE':'{}'}.format(a, today, color)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'**dict**' object has *no attribute* '**format**' , so replacement is defined incorrectly.

If you change it like this, it will be fine.

```
replacements = {'SCORE': a, 'CURRDATE': today, 'COLORCODE': color}
```

Comment: Tried that but that is replacing CURRDATE with today what i am trying is to replace CURRDATE with value in today that is 09/27/2022

Comment: for date you should use it like this
`import datetime` and 
`today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`